# How to add 'load more' functionality to items on a page with vanilla JS?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to set up 'load more' functionality on some items on a page. Originally, I found this done in jQuery. I'm trying to convert this jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".news-item").slice(0, 9).removeClass('hidden');
  $("#loadMore").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".news-item:hidden").slice(0, 6).removeClass('hidden').fadeIn("slow");

    if ($(".news-item:hidden").length == 0) {
      $("#loadMore").fadeOut("slow");
    }
  });
})
```

...into vanilla js:
This is how far I've gotten... But, I'm unable to get the additional items to load.

```
const hiddenItems = document.querySelectorAll('.hidden');
const loadMore = document.getElementById('loadmore');

document.querySelectorAll('.news-item:nth-child(-n+9)').forEach(
  elem => elem.classList.remove('hidden')
);

loadmore.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  document.querySelectorAll('.news-item:hidden:nth-child(-n+6)').forEach(
    elem => elem.classList.remove('hidden')
  )
  if (hiddenItems.length == 0) {
    loadMore.classList.add('hidden');
  }
});
```

```js
const hiddenItems = document.querySelectorAll('.hidden');
const loadMore = document.getElementById('loadmore');

document.querySelectorAll('.news-item:nth-child(-n+9)').forEach(
  elem => elem.classList.remove('hidden')
);

loadmore.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  document.querySelectorAll('.news-item:hidden:nth-child(-n+6)').forEach(
    elem => elem.classList.remove('hidden')
  )
  if (hiddenItems.length == 0) {
    loadMore.classList.add('hidden');
  }
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="news-item hidden">News Item</div>
  <div class="news-item hidden">News Item</div>
  <div class="news-item hidden">News Item</div>
  <div class="news-item hidden">News Item</div>
  <div class="news-item hidden">News Item</div>
  <div class="news-item hidden">News Item</div>
  <div class="news-item hidden">News Item</div>
  <div class="news-item hidden">News Item</div>
  <div class="news-item hidden">News Item</div>
  <div class="news-item hidden">News Item</div>
  <div class="news-item hidden">News Item</div>
  <div class="news-item hidden">News Item</div>
  <div class="news-item hidden">News Item</div>
  <div class="news-item hidden">News Item</div>
  <div class="news-item hidden">News Item</div>
  <div class="news-item hidden">News Item</div>
  <div class="news-item hidden">News Item</div>
  <div class="news-item hidden">News Item</div>
  <div class="news-item hidden">News Item</div>
  <div class="news-item hidden">News Item</div>
  <div class="news-item hidden">News Item</div>
  <div class="news-item hidden">News Item</div>
  <div class="news-item hidden">News Item</div>
  <div class="news-item hidden">News Item</div>
  <div class="news-item hidden">News Item</div>
  <div class="news-item hidden">News Item</div>
  <div class="news-item hidden">News Item</div>
  <div class="news-item hidden">News Item</div>
  <div class="news-item hidden">News Item</div>
  <div class="news-item hidden">News Item</div>
  <button type="button" id="loadmore">Load More</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Says you have an invalid selector which is probably this one `:hidden`

Comment: Right. It's what I'm trying to fix.

Comment: I think it has to be `.hidden`, not `:hidden`. It's a class name, not a sudo selector

Comment: That confused me, too. In the original jQuery script, `.hidden` is a class, but then I saw `$(".news-item:hidden")` and thought it needed to be the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been trying doing it by `:nth-child()` approach but i couldn't make it. It selects the ones that is not hidden anymore as well.

So i did it with `splice`, similar to jQuery which use `slice`. Here:

```js
const loadMore = document.getElementById('loadmore');
const hid = [...document.querySelectorAll('.news-item.hidden')];

hid.splice(0, 9).forEach(
  elem => elem.classList.remove('hidden')
);

loadmore.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  
  hid.splice(0, 6).forEach(
    elem => elem.classList.remove('hidden')
  )
  
  if (hid.length == 0) {
    loadMore.classList.add('hidden');
  }
});
```

```css
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="news-item hidden">News Item</div>
  <div class="news-item hidden">News Item</div>
  <div class="news-item hidden">News Item</div>
  <div class="news-item hidden">News Item</div>
  <div class="news-item hidden">News Item</div>
  <div class="news-item hidden">News Item</div>
  <div class="news-item hidden">News Item</div>
  <div class="news-item hidden">News Item</div>
  <div class="news-item hidden">News Item</div>
  <div class="news-item hidden">News Item</div>
  <div class="news-item hidden">News Item</div>
  <div class="news-item hidden">News Item</div>
  <div class="news-item hidden">News Item</div>
  <div class="news-item hidden">News Item</div>
  <div class="news-item hidden">News Item</div>
  <div class="news-item hidden">News Item</div>
  <div class="news-item hidden">News Item</div>
  <div class="news-item hidden">News Item</div>
  <div class="news-item hidden">News Item</div>
  <div class="news-item hidden">News Item</div>
  <div class="news-item hidden">News Item</div>
  <div class="news-item hidden">News Item</div>
  <div class="news-item hidden">News Item</div>
  <div class="news-item hidden">News Item</div>
  <div class="news-item hidden">News Item</div>
  <div class="news-item hidden">News Item</div>
  <div class="news-item hidden">News Item</div>
  <div class="news-item hidden">News Item</div>
  <div class="news-item hidden">News Item</div>
  <div class="news-item hidden">News Item</div>
  <button type="button" id="loadmore">Load More</button>
</div>
```